# Can I grant privileges to a Postgres user on all schemas belonging to a database with one command or script?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Let's say I have 20 different schemas on a Postgres database. I create a new user *theUser* and now I want to grant only the SELECT and INSERT privileges for this user on *all* schemas. Is there an easy way/script to do that?

Comment: Does postgres support roles like SQL 20xx?

Comment: @CoveGeek I don't know if they are "like SQL 20xx", but it has had roles for a long time.

Comment: which changes more often: the number of users or the number of schemas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using DO, cursors, execute, and the pg_namespace table:

```
DO $$DECLARE _schema record; _user name := '<your_username>'
BEGIN
  FOR _schema IN
    SELECT * FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspowner > 10 OR nspname = 'public'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON SCHEMA '||
            quote_ident(_schema.nspname)||' TO '||quote_ident(_user);
  END LOOP;
END;$$;
```